# Unable to fetch get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having the below htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dashboard-detailed-view-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^dashboard-detailed-view-(.*)$ /rat/view/dashboard-detailed-view.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And having this URL

> http://localhost/dashboard-detailed-view-absence?dept=ABS&test=23

When I try to get the parameters in GET variable, only page value is coming.
Other parameters dept & test parameters unable to fetch

Result from php(print_r($_GET))

```
 Array ( [page] => absence )
```

I want to get all the three(page,dept,test) parameters in GET

Comment: Add QSA flag to your rule.

Comment: i am unable to see any `page` parameter in your given URL

Comment: In htacess page=$1 and in URL `absence` text

Comment: @starkeen It works Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine new and old querystrings you need to use QSA flag

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dashboard-detailed-view-(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^dashboard-detailed-view-(.*)$ /rat/view/dashboard-detailed-view.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```